# Upload from Client Browser to Google Cloud Storage Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I am using Google Cloud Storage. To upload to cloud storage I have looked at different methods. The method I find most common is that the file is sent to the server, and from there it is sent to Google Cloud storage.

I want to move the file directly from the user's web browser to Google Cloud Storage. I can't find any tutorials related to this. I have read through the Google API Client SDK for JavaScript.

Going through the Google API reference, it states that files can be transferred using a HTTP request. But I am confused about how to do it using the [API client library for JavaScript.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/)

People here would require to share some code. But I haven't written any code, I have failed in finding a method to do the job.

Comment: The usual approach is to use a "put" call using the firebase storage api. References are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: this is a bad idea because it basically allows anyone to upload anything, whereas going though a server gives you the opportunity to police and validate the submission and hides your API key.

Comment: I'm not sure from the question that you want the user to to do this without authenticating. Is that what you are after, or are you looking for an authenticated user to be able to do this?

Comment: Is there still no npm package for this in 2022?

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT 1: Untested Sample Code**

So I got really interested in this, and had a few minutes to throw some code together. I decided to build a tiny Express server to get the access token, but still do the upload from the client. I used `fetch` to do the upload instead of the client library.

I don't have a Google cloud account, and thus have not tested this, so I can't confirm that it works, but I can't see why it shouldn't. Code is [on my GitHub here](https://github.com/joepin/google-cloud-storage).

Please read through it and make the necessary changes before attempting to run it. Most notably, you need to specify the location of the private key file, as well as ensure that it's there, and you need to set the bucket name in `index.html`.

**End of edit 1**

Disclaimer: I've only ever used the Node.js Google client library for sending emails, but I think I have a basic grasp of Google's APIs.

In order to use any Google service, we need access tokens to verify our identity; however, since we are looking to allow any user to upload to our own Cloud Storage bucket, we do not need to go through the standard OAuth process.

Google provides what they call a service account, which is an account that we use to identify instances of our own apps accessing our own resources. Whereas in a standard OAuth process we'd need to identify our app to the service, have the user consent to using our app (and thus grant us permission), get an access token for that specific user, and then make requests to the service; with a service account, we can skip the user consent process, since we are, in a sense, our own user. Using a service account enables us to simply use our credentials generated from the Google API console to generate a JWT (JSON web token), which we then use to get an access token, which we use to make requests to the cloud storage service. See [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for Google's guide on this process.

In the past, I've used packages like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to generate JWT's, but I couldn't find any client libraries for encoding JWT's; mostly because they are generated almost exclusively on servers. However, I found [this tutorial](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2014/11/27/creating-json-web-token-in-javascript.html), which, at a cursory glance, seems sufficient enough to write our own encoding algorithm.

I'd like to point out here that opening an app to allow the public free access to your Google resources may prove detrimental to you or your organization in the future, as I'm sure you've considered. This is a major security risk, which is why all the tutorials you've seen so far have implemented two consecutive uploads.

If it were me, I would at least do the first part of the authentication process on my server: when the user is ready to upload, I would send a request to my server to generate the access token for Google services using my service account's credentials, and then I would send each user a new access token that my server generated. This way, I have an added layer of security between the outside world and my Google account, as the burden of the authentication lies with my server, and only the uploading gets done by the client.

Anyways, once we have the access token, we can utilize the [CORS feature that Google provides](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) to upload files to our bucket. This feature allows us to use standard `XHR 2` requests to use Google's services, and is essentially designed to be used in place of the [JavaScript client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js). I would prefer to use the CORS feature over the client library only because I think it's a little more straightforward, and slightly more flexible in its implementation. (I haven't tested this, but I think `fetch` would work here just as well as `XHR 2`.).

From here, we'd need to get the file from the user, as well as any information we want from them regarding the file (read: file name), and then make a `POST` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/<BUCKET_NAME_HERE>/o` (replacing  with the name of your bucket, of course) with the access token added to the URL as per the *Making authenticated requests* section of the [CORS feature page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) and whatever other parameters in the body/query string that you wish to include, as per the [Cloud Storage API documentation on inserting an object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert). An API listing for the Cloud Storage service can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/) for reference.

As I've never done this before, and I don't have the ability to test this out, I don't have any sample code to include with my answer, but I hope that my post is clear enough that putting together the code should be relatively straightforward from here.

Just to set the record straight, I've always found OAuth to be pretty confusing, and have generally shied away from playing with it due to my fear of its unknowns. However, I think I've finally mastered it, especially after this post, so I can't wait to get a free hour to play around with it.

Please let me know if anything I said is not clear or coherent.